# When are Feynman diagrams Borel summable?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, feynman-diagrams

I've been trying to understand Feynman diagrams more rigorously, and it seems that everything can be rigorously defined as long as the Feynman diagrams are Borel summable. However, are there any good indicators/lemmas of when a series of Feynman diagrams are Borel summable?

Indeed, consider the simple $\phi^4$ theory on a finite lattice $\Lambda \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^d$. Notice that exists a well-defined Gaussian measure $\mu_G$ on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and thus it's possible to compute correlation functions $G_\lambda(x,y)$ with respect to the distribution
$$
\propto\exp\left(-\lambda \sum_{x\in \Lambda} \phi(x)^4\right) d\mu_G
$$
where $\lambda$ is the coupling constant. It's not too hard to check that $G_\lambda (x,y)$ is smooth (though not analytic) at $\lambda=0$ and its Taylor series coefficients can be represented as Feynman diagrams, i.e., the terms $a_n \lambda^n$ are calculated using the Feynman diagrams.

Now if the series $\sum a_n\lambda^n$ were asymptotic to $G_\lambda (x,y)$ and also Borel summable, then the error of the first $N$ terms would be $\propto N! \lambda^N$.
A quick plot would see that this error is quite small for the first few terms if $\lambda>0$ is small.

**Question**. In general, I don't quite see why the formal series $\sum a_n\lambda^n$ is Borel summable to $G_\lambda (x,y)$? Is this at least true for the $\phi^4$ theory on a finite lattice $\Lambda$?

Comment: The usual expectation is that the sum of the series of Feynman diagrams is actually going to be divergent (an asymptotic series), not actually summable at all.

Comment: @Buzz Maybe I'm not being clear enough, but the series being asymptotic is part of the definition of Borel summability. So I guess my question is why is the usual expectation correct?

Comment: Are you aware of the details of the Borel transform and integral? My knowledge is basic at best, but looking at section 2.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.04861.pdf), it seems to me that it could depend on whether the Borel integral converges (if it doesn't, the original asymptotic, and Borel series do not match). Perhaps asking about the specific conditions under which it doesn't would yield your answer? As the section describes, this is not always the case and is named the ''renormalon''.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes this theory is Borel summable even after taking the box $\Lambda$ to infinity.
To learn about these things look at the pedagogical paper ["Constructive field theory in zero dimension"](https://doi.org/10.1155/2009/180159) by Rivasseau.

Note that in principle to show a model is Borel summable, the *naive* procedure is to: 1) define the Borel transform, i.e., the function with power series coefficients given by the original ones divided by $n!$, 2) analytically continue in a strip around the positive real axis, 3) take an integral transform to recover the wanted function, i.e., some correlation function.

However, this almost never is how one proves Borel summability because step 2) is too hard to do if all one knows is the perturbation series. What is usually done is to construct the correlation by other means and then afterwards show that it is indeed the Borel sum of the perturbative series. This only requires some precise $n!$ remainder estimates. This is explained in the above article by Rivasseau.
For examples of QFT models without UV cutoff where this has been done in a *mathematically rigorous* way see the article by Eckmann, Magnen, Sénéor in CMP on [$\phi^2$ in 2d](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-39/issue-4/Decay-properties-and-Borel-summability-for-the-Schwinger-functions-in/cmp/1103860232.full), by Magnen and Sénéor on [$\phi^4$ in 3d](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-56/issue-3/Phase-space-cell-expansion-and-Borel-summability-for-the-Euclidean/cmp/1103901188.full) and by Feldman, Magnen, Rivasseau and Sénéor for [massive Gross-Neveu in 2d](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-103/issue-1/A-renormalizable-field-theory--the-massive-Gross-Neveu-model/cmp/1104114625.full) as well as [infrared $\phi^4$ in 4d](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-109/issue-3/Construction-and-Borel-summability-of-infrared-Phi4_4-by-a-phase/cmp/1104116964.full).